# Flutter: Only static members can be accessed in initializers

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to check if a variable is true or false. I get the data from firestore in previous screens. I made a model of "place". Normally, I use the data by using: widget.currentPlace."dataIWant", that works. But now, it gives the error: Only static members can be accessed in intializers. Is there a solution for this?

Thanks!

```
class EditBizHours extends StatefulWidget {
  final Place currentPlace;

  EditBizHours({this.currentPlace});

  @override
  _EditBizHoursState createState() => _EditBizHoursState();
}

class _EditBizHoursState extends State<EditBizHours> {
  bool openMO = widget.currentPlace.openMO;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it in initState(). like this:

```
class _EditBizHoursState extends State<EditBizHours> {
    bool openMO;

    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();
        openMO = widget.currentPlace.openMO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thak you very much! Yeah that's a great solution! thanks!